# Is there a contradiction between 7:22 and 7:27?

Tags: contradiction

> Quran chapter Al A'raf verse 22 (7:22)
>
> > So he brought about their fall through deception. And when they tasted of the tree, their nakedness was exposed to them, prompting them to cover themselves with leaves from Paradise. Then their Lord called out to them, “Did I not forbid you from that tree and ˹did I not˺ tell you that Satan is your sworn enemy?”
> > Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran
> >
> > So he made them fall, through deception. And when they tasted of the tree, their private parts became apparent to them, and they began to fasten together over themselves from the leaves of Paradise. And their Lord called to them, "Did I not forbid you from that tree and tell you that Satan is to you a clear enemy?"
> > Saheeh International

> Quran chapter Al A'raf verse 27 (7:27)
>
> > O children of Adam! Do not let Satan deceive you as he tempted your parents out of Paradise and caused their cover to be removed in order to expose their nakedness. Surely he and his soldiers watch you from where you cannot see them. We have made the devils allies of those who disbelieve.
> > Dr. Mustafa Khattab, the Clear Quran
> >
> > O children of Adam, let not Satan tempt you as he removed your parents from Paradise, stripping them of their clothing1 to show them their private parts. Indeed, he sees you, he and his tribe, from where you do not see them. Indeed, We have made the devils allies to those who do not believe.
> > Saheeh International

---

---

**MY question : In first(7:22) verse Allah say we're naked and they started to cover their body with leaves, but in second (7:27) it is written Satan removed their clothes and exposed their nakedness. 
 Is there any contradiction because one verse say they were naked and other verse says they were wearing clothes and Satan removed them** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were clothed when they were admitted to paradise, as Allah said to them:

> إن لك ألا تجوع فيها ولا تعرى
>
> Indeed, it is [promised] for you not to be hungry therein or be unclothed.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 20:118](http://quran.com/20/118)</sup>

However **after** falling into satan's deception and eating from the forbidden tree, their clothing vanished and they became naked. And so they began to cover themselves with the leaves of paradise.

It is that simple.

Comment: Oooo, Okay thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Where is the contradiction?

Please note that this is based on the simple understanding of the qur'an for more details and background information I'd need to consult a tafsir or other verses that might be related here my focus was on the story told in surat al-'A' araaf.

Verse 7:22 says in simple words: That after listening to Satan -who influenced them- they ate from the tree and that's why their nakedness was shown.
While verse 7:27 says don't listen to Satan for he caused them to stand "naked".

There is absolutely no contradiction here! You just must read the verse 7:22 in the context of the prior verses and understand it. And the same applies to verse 7:27.

Comment: it clearly says "stripping them of their clothing" so they were wearing clothes

Comment: @Blue I see, was the qur'an revealed in English? Should the qur'an be understood out of context?

Comment: well no, so how should we understand these verse. Can you please explain it in detail, because I have seen a [video of a ex muslim](https://youtu.be/tw_a9dNQM7g) see this. Then you can explain it better. And please explain it in detail or in brief

Comment: I think I failed to make clear or to express my self in question.

Comment: @user43568 for details consulting a tafsir is needed. Actually I'm not able to do that much research due to health conditions.